# Multiple domain and range in objectProperty?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, rdfs

I want to create an ontology with Protege that contains two classes, **Animal** and **FatherAnimal**, and the object property **hasFather**, with domain **Animal** and range **FatherAnimal**.

Also, I create two other classes: **Son** and **Father** which are linked with the same object property, **hasFather**. The problem here is that I'm not allowed to create multiple domain and range for the same object property. I'd really like to avoid creating a new object property. Is there any other solution?

Comment: "The problem here is that I'm not allowed to create multiple domain and range for the same objectProperty." You can specify multiple domains and ranges on ObjectProperties in OWL and Protege.

Comment: Yes i know but as you said the interpretation is the intersection. Sorry, i wasn't clear enough. Also a union of these classes would not be a solution in my case because i want the reasoner to give me an error when i use the objectProperty with different classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not really clear what the problem is.  You *can* add multiple domains and ranges to object properties, but the interpretation is the intersection.  That means that you if say, for instance,

```
hasFather rdfs:domain Son
hasFather rdfs:domain Animal
```

whenever you have

```
X hasFather Y
```

you'll be able to infer

```
X rdf:type Son
X rdf:type Animal
```

which probably isn't what you want.

As I see it, you could do this:

- Don't declare any domain or range on **hasFather**.  There's no need to do that.  You can just declare the property, and then use it however you see fit.

If you want a bit more type inference available to you, then you could also add two subclass axioms:

Son **SubClassOf** (hasFather **only** Father)
        Animal **SubClassOf** (hasFather **only** AnimalFather)

these axioms say that *if* something is a **Son** and it's related to something by the property **hasFather**, *then* that something is an instance of **Father**.  Similiary, *if* something is an **Animal** and is related to something by the property **hasFather**, *then* that something is an instance of **AnimalFather**.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you very very much! It is exactly what i needed. I have seen that sb can define a concept like that as a subclass but i didn't know the meaning. Thank you again! :)

Comment: the definition of `rdfs:domain` that states what this answer explains, can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domain